# How to create a table by restructuring a MALLET output file?

Tags: r, dataframe, mallet

I'm using [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) for topic analysis which is outputting results in text files ("topics.txt") of several thousand rows and a hundred or so rows where each row consists of tab-separated variables like this:

```
Num1 text1 topic1 proportion1 topic2 proportion2 topic3 proportion3,  etc.
Num2 text2 topic1 proportion1 topic2 proportion2 topic3 proportion3,  etc.
Num3 text3 topic1 proportion1 topic2 proportion2 topic3 proportion3,  etc.
```

Here's a snippet of the actual data:

```
> dat[1:5,1:10]

  V1 V2 V3    V4 V5        V6 V7        V8 V9        V10
1  0 10.txt   27 0.4560785 23 0.3040853 20 0.1315621 21 0.03632624
2  1 1001.txt 20 0.2660085 12 0.2099153  8 0.1699586 13 0.16922928
3  2 1002.txt 16 0.3341721  2 0.1747023 10 0.1360454 12 0.07507119
4  3 1003.txt 12 0.5366148  8 0.2255179 18 0.1388561  0 0.01867091
5  4 1005.txt 16 0.2363206  0 0.2214441 24 0.1914769  7 0.17760521
```

I'm trying to use **R** to convert this output into a data table where the topics are column headers and each topic contains the values of the variable 'proportion' directly to the right hand side of each variable 'topic', for each value of 'text'. Like this:

```
      topic1       topic2       topic3
text1 proportion1  proportion2  proportion3
text2 proportion1  proportion2  proportion3
```

or with the data snippet above, like so:

```
           0         2         7         8         10        12        13        16        18       20        21         23        24         27
10.txt     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0        0.1315621 0.03632624 0.3040853 0          0.4560785        
1001.txt   0         0         0         0.1699586 0         0.2099153 0.1692292 0         0        0.2660085 0          0         0          0
1002.txt   0         0.1747023 0         0         0.1360454 0.0750711 0         0.3341721 0        0         0          0         0          0
1003.txt   0.0186709 0         0         0.2255179 0         0.5366148 0         0         0.138856 0         0          0         0          0
1005.txt   0.2214441 0         0.1776052 0         0         0         0         0.2363206 0        0         0          0         0.1914769  0
```

This is the **R** code I've got to do the job, sent from a friend, but it doesn't work for me (and I don't know enough about it to fix it myself):

```
##########################################
dat<-read.table("topics.txt", header=F, sep="\t")
datnames<-subset(dat, select=2)
dat2<-subset(dat, select=3:length(dat))
y <- data.frame(topic=character(0),proportion=character(0),text=character(0))
for(i in seq(1, length(dat2), 2)){ 
z<-i+1
x<-dat2[,i:z]
x<-cbind(x, datnames)
colnames(x)<-c("topic","proportion", "text")
y<-rbind(y, x)
}

# Right at this step at the end of the block 
# I get this message that may indicate the problem:
# Error in c(in c("topic", "proportion", "text") : unused argument(s) ("text")

y[is.na(y)] <- 0 
xdat<-xtabs(proportion ~ text+topic, data=y)  
write.table(xdat, file="topicMatrix.txt", sep="\t", eol = "\n", quote=TRUE, col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE)
##########################################
```

I'd be most grateful for any suggestions on how I can get this code working. My problem may be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584383/r-converting-dataframe-to-table) and possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950304/reading-and-constructing-a-table-from-a-data-frame-with-multiple-columns-using-r) also, but I don't yet have the skills to make immediate use of the answers to those questions.

Comment: You are not going to get much help unless you offer a real data structure.... one with number for those proportions. Use dput(head(dat,20))

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've added some in.

Comment: I should also add that removing objects with `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))` before trying my friend's code changed the problem slightly so that at the end of his block the error message changed to "Error in [.data.frame`(dat2, , i:z) : undefined columns selected". Regardless of that, I think the answer from @Ramnath is a promising alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach to your problem

```
 dat <-read.table(as.is = TRUE, header = FALSE, textConnection(
  "Num1 text1 topic1 proportion1 topic2 proportion2 topic3 proportion3
   Num2 text2 topic1 proportion1 topic2 proportion2 topic3 proportion3
   Num3 text3 topic1 proportion1 topic2 proportion2 topic3 proportion3"))

 NTOPICS = 3 
 nam <- c('num', 'text', 
   paste(c('topic', 'proportion'), rep(1:NTOPICS, each = 2), sep = ""))

 dat_l <- reshape(setNames(dat, nam), varying = 3:length(nam), direction = 'long',
   sep = "")
 reshape2::dcast(dat_l, num + text ~ topic, value_var = 'proportion')

num  text      topic1      topic2      topic3
1 Num1 text1 proportion1 proportion2 proportion3
2 Num2 text2 proportion1 proportion2 proportion3
3 Num3 text3 proportion1 proportion2 proportion3
```

EDIT. This will work irrespective of whether the proportions are text or numbers. You can also modify `NTOPICS` to suit the number of topics you have

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I can reproduce your example and make it work on my full set of data. How about if we change     `dat_l <- reshape(setNames(dat, nam), varying = 3:8, direction = 'long',sep = "")`  to `dat_l <- reshape(setNames(dat, nam), varying = 3:((NTOPICS*2)+2), direction = 'long',sep = "")`  That seems to make it more general and efficient when working with different numbers of topics.

Comment: Minor edit to remove having to enter the number of topics
`###########`
`rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))`
`dat<-read.table("topics.txt", header=F, sep="\t")`
`NTOPICS = (ncol(dat)-4)/2`
 `nam <- c('num', 'text',` 
   `paste(c('topic', 'proportion'), rep(1:NTOPICS, each = 2), sep = ""))`
`dat_l <- reshape(setNames(dat, nam), varying = 3:length(nam), direction = 'long',sep = "")`
`dat_out<- reshape2::dcast(dat_l, num + text ~ topic, value_var = 'proportion')`
`write.csv(dat_out,"dat_out.csv")`
############

Answer (score 2):

You can get this into a long format but to go further required real data. 
**EDITED** after data offered. Still not sure about the overall structure of what is coming from MALLET, but at least the R functions are demonstrated. This approach has the "feature" that proportions are summed if there are overlapping topics. Depending on the data layout that may be an advantage or not.

```
dat <-read.table(textConnection("  V1 V2 V3  V4 V5  V6 V7  V8 V9  V10
1  0 10.txt   27 0.4560785 23 0.3040853 20 0.1315621 21 0.03632624
2  1 1001.txt 20 0.2660085 12 0.2099153  8 0.1699586 13 0.16922928
3  2 1002.txt 16 0.3341721  2 0.1747023 10 0.1360454 12 0.07507119
4  3 1003.txt 12 0.5366148  8 0.2255179 18 0.1388561  0 0.01867091
5  4 1005.txt 16 0.2363206  0 0.2214441 24 0.1914769  7 0.17760521
"), 
          header=TRUE)
 ldat <- reshape(dat, idvar=1:2, varying=list(topics=c("V3", "V5", "V7", "V9"), 
                                          props=c("V4", "V6", "V8", "V10")), 
                       direction="long")
####------------------####
    > ldat
             V1       V2 time V3         V4
0.10.txt.1    0   10.txt    1 27 0.45607850
1.1001.txt.1  1 1001.txt    1 20 0.26600850
2.1002.txt.1  2 1002.txt    1 16 0.33417210
3.1003.txt.1  3 1003.txt    1 12 0.53661480
4.1005.txt.1  4 1005.txt    1 16 0.23632060
0.10.txt.2    0   10.txt    2 23 0.30408530
1.1001.txt.2  1 1001.txt    2 12 0.20991530
2.1002.txt.2  2 1002.txt    2  2 0.17470230
3.1003.txt.2  3 1003.txt    2  8 0.22551790
4.1005.txt.2  4 1005.txt    2  0 0.22144410
0.10.txt.3    0   10.txt    3 20 0.13156210
1.1001.txt.3  1 1001.txt    3  8 0.16995860
2.1002.txt.3  2 1002.txt    3 10 0.13604540
3.1003.txt.3  3 1003.txt    3 18 0.13885610
4.1005.txt.3  4 1005.txt    3 24 0.19147690
0.10.txt.4    0   10.txt    4 21 0.03632624
1.1001.txt.4  1 1001.txt    4 13 0.16922928
2.1002.txt.4  2 1002.txt    4 12 0.07507119
3.1003.txt.4  3 1003.txt    4  0 0.01867091
4.1005.txt.4  4 1005.txt    4  7 0.17760521
```

Now can show you how to use xtabs() since those "proportions" are "numeric".  Something like this may eventually be what you want. I was surprised that the topics were also integers but perhaps there is a mapping from topic numbers to topic names?:

```
> xtabs(V4 ~ V3 + V2, data=ldat)
    V2
V3       10.txt   1001.txt   1002.txt   1003.txt   1005.txt
  0  0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.01867091 0.22144410
  2  0.00000000 0.00000000 0.17470230 0.00000000 0.00000000
  7  0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.17760521
  8  0.00000000 0.16995860 0.00000000 0.22551790 0.00000000
  10 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.13604540 0.00000000 0.00000000
  12 0.00000000 0.20991530 0.07507119 0.53661480 0.00000000
  13 0.00000000 0.16922928 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  16 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.33417210 0.00000000 0.23632060
  18 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.13885610 0.00000000
  20 0.13156210 0.26600850 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  21 0.03632624 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  23 0.30408530 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  24 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.19147690
  27 0.45607850 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion. I can reproduce your results. How could it be generalized for 30 (or 100 or more) topics?

Comment: If the column names are very regular then the "varying" argument can be something like `topics=paste("V", seq(1, 100, by=2), sep="")` and `props=paste("V", seq(2, 100, by=2), sep="")`

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. Unfortunately I can't see why your suggestion isn't working for me, but the code from @Ramnath does the job, so I'm happy to close the case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Returning to this problem, I've found that the `reshape` function is far too demanding on memory, so I use a `data.table` method instead. A few more steps, but a huge amount faster and substantially less memory intensive.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "V1 V2 V3    V4 V5        V6 V7        V8 V9        V10
1  0 10.txt   27 0.4560785 23 0.3040853 20 0.1315621 21 0.03632624
2  1 1001.txt 20 0.2660085 12 0.2099153  8 0.1699586 13 0.16922928
3  2 1002.txt 16 0.3341721  2 0.1747023 10 0.1360454 12 0.07507119
4  3 1003.txt 12 0.5366148  8 0.2255179 18 0.1388561  0 0.01867091
5  4 1005.txt 16 0.2363206  0 0.2214441 24 0.1914769  7 0.17760521")

dat$V11 <- rep(NA, 5) # my real data has this extra unwanted col
dat <- data.table(dat)

# get document number
docnum <- dat$V1
# get text number
txt <- dat$V2

# remove doc num and text num so we just have topic and props
dat1 <- dat[ ,c("V1","V2", paste0("V", ncol(dat))) := NULL]
# get topic numbers
n <- ncol(dat1) 
tops <- apply(dat1, 1, function(i) i[seq(1, n, 2)])
# get props 
props <- apply(dat1, 1, function(i) i[seq(2, n, 2)])

# put topics and props together
tp <- lapply(1:ncol(tops), function(i) data.frame(tops[,i], props[,i]))
names(tp) <- txt
# make into long table
dt <- data.table::rbindlist(tp)
dt$doc <- unlist(lapply(txt, function(i) rep(i, ncol(dat1)/2)))
dt$docnum <- unlist(lapply(docnum, function(i) rep(i, ncol(dat1)/2)))

# reshape to wide
library(data.table)
setkey(dt, tops...i., doc)
out <- dt[CJ(unique(tops...i.), unique(doc))][, as.list(props...i.), by=tops...i.]
setnames(out, c("topic", as.character(txt)))

# transpose to have table of docs (rows) and columns (topics) 
tout <- data.table(t(out))
setnames(tout, unname(as.character(tout[1,])))
tout <- tout[-1,]
row.names(tout) <- txt 

# replace NA with zero
tout[is.na(tout)] <- 0
```

And here's the output, docs as rows, topics as columns, doc names are in the rownames, which are not printed, but available for later use.

```
tout

            0         2         7         8        10         12        13        16        18
1: 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2: 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1699586 0.0000000 0.20991530 0.1692293 0.0000000 0.0000000
3: 0.00000000 0.1747023 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1360454 0.07507119 0.0000000 0.3341721 0.0000000
4: 0.01867091 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2255179 0.0000000 0.53661480 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1388561
5: 0.22144410 0.0000000 0.1776052 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.2363206 0.0000000
          20         21        23        24        27
1: 0.1315621 0.03632624 0.3040853 0.0000000 0.4560785
2: 0.2660085 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
3: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
4: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
5: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.1914769 0.0000000
```